# How to use multiple django-markdownx editors on the same page?

Tags: django, markdown, python-markdown

I have followed http://neutronx.github.io/django-markdownx/js/docs/markdownx.html#MarkdownX docs but can't get it done properly.

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/27001046/41530962-7c225130-730f-11e8-9dd0-b915f08c3bc2.png]

What is the correct way to setup two or more editors in the same page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to set it up that way. MarkdownX is already initiated as your load `{{form}}` and `{{form.media}}`, so it has no meaning. Now, coming to your question. Using two editors on the same page in really straight forward.

in your `forms.py`:

```
from django import forms
from markdownx.fields import MarkdownxFormField


class FirstForm(forms.Form):
    yourfirstfield = MarkdownxFormField()


class SecondForm(forms.Form):
    yoursecondfield = MarkdownxFormField()
```

in your `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import FirstForm, SecondForm


def form_view(request):
    context = {
        'first_form': FirstForm,
        'second_form': SecondForm
    }
    return render(request, 'form_template.html', context)
```

in your `form_template.html`:

```
<form>
    <p>{{first_form}}</p>
    <p>{{second_form}}</p>
</form>
```

I hope that helps!